# Creating a development environment on Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, virtual-machine

Is it still possible to create a quick development environment on Azure for SharePoint 2013 or 2016?

Like it's described in this very old blog post:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2013/09/26/create-sharepoint-2013-development-environments-quickly-on-azure/

It seems to me that the indicated image "Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate RC" isn't available any longer. Has it been replaced with something else?

Also, I have checked out a few posts here but it seems that they arent't relevant anymore. This one here is 5 year old (and quite obscure to me..)

[SP2013 Development Environment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71745/sp2013-development-environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be two images which both are trial versions of SharePoint 2013/2016

[image: trialversions SharePoint]

There is also two solutiontemplates for SharePoint 2013

[image]

Microsoft has a doc describing on how to setup an 2013 dev environment in azure. There is also an article describing how to setup an 2016 environment. If you want to setup one manually.

[SharePoint 2013 dev/test environments in Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/sharepoint-2013-dev-test-environments-in-azure)

[SharePoint Server 2016 dev/test environment in Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/sharepoint-server-2016-dev-test-environment-in-azure)

Yes, Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate RC has been replaced many times since then. Have a look at this list of getting started articles for more up to date information regarding developing for SharePoint.

[Get started (SharePoint development in Visual Studio)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/getting-started-sharepoint-development-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you. I suppose the virtual machine installed by these images don't have visual studio though. Is it correct?

Comment: That I cant give you a sure answer for but I would think not.